# Converting very large 3D Python list to numpy array never finishes

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a very large 3D Python list (1486x4656x34) of floating point numbers, which I need to compute the mean along axis 0 (to yield a 4656x34 result). I have attempted to do this with `np.mean(arr, axis=0)`, but the method never seems to complete its execution (or if it does, it takes more time than I have available to wait for it).

A similar issue occurs when running other numpy methods on the array, including `np.array()`, which makes me think the issue is related to converting this list to a numpy array. I don't really understand why this is occurring; This array is large, but doesn't seem unmanageably large, and I'm not throttling on CPU usage or running out of memory. Does anyone know why this issue might be occurring, and what I can do to get around it?

Comment: *(Posted on behalf of user with too low reputation to comment)* "Where does your data come from ? If you could load it directly in a numpy array it would be much faster."

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that you do not in fact have an entirely regular shape.  I cannot reproduce the problem if you do, but can readily reproduce it if the shape is irregular (which results in an array of objects rather than an array of numbers).  Timings shown below are on a reasonably old machine.

```
import numpy as np
import time

n0 = 1846
n1 = 4656
n2 = 34

t0 = time.time()

biglist = [[[1. for k in range(n2)] for j in range(n1)] for i in range(n0)]

t1 = time.time()
print(t1 - t0)  # order of 20 seconds to construct the nested list

bigarr = np.array(biglist)

t2 = time.time()
print(t2 - t1)  # order of 10 seconds to convert to np.array

mean = np.mean(bigarr, axis=0)

t3 = time.time()
print(t3 - t2)  # about 0.3 seconds

biglist[456][3265].pop()  # now disrupt the regular shape

t3a = time.time()
bigarr = np.array(biglist)

t4 = time.time()
print(t4 - t3a)  # now really quick (about 1s) to convert to array, but all 
                 # it is doing is making an (2d) array of object references
                 # because the shapes don't match (dtype = object)

mean = np.mean(bigarr, axis=0)  # this takes forever...
                                # (not even sure what the result
                                # should look like)
```

To test:

- explicitly convert to array
- test the `dtype` of the array before attempting to call `np.mean`